# Как правильно считать элементы из файла в массив java

Tags: java, файлы

Как правильно считать элементы из файла в массив. И что бы потом этот массив можно было передавать другим методам, например для сортировки. Файл имеет такую структуру:

```
14

2

4

6
```

Comment: [`int[] ints = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181720/5812238)

Comment: @diraria может юыть оформите это в виде ответа?

Comment: @PauloBerezini, ну вообще мне хотелось бы узнать у ТС, что он имеет в виду под элементами (обязательно ли это числа). Можете вы оформить, я плюсану)

Comment: @diraria `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` вот такие пироги =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читать из файла строки в лист с помощью классического BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("e:\\test.txt"));
String str;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str = reader.readLine()) != null ){
    if(!str.isEmpty()){
    list.add(str);
    System.out.println(str);
}}
String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Результат:

`List<String> list = {'14', '2', '4', '6'}`

Читать из файла строки с помощью стрима в лист:

```
String fileName = "e:\\test.txt";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        String str;
        list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Результат:

`List<String> list = {'14', '', '2', '', '4', '', '6'}`