# Как получить корректное значение при форматирование даты

Tags: php

Не могу понять ошибку при форматировании даты. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в таком коде я получаю: 1970-01-01

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00", date("Y-m-01"))
```

Вместо того что бы получить 2017-10-04 00:00:00

Comment: `почему в таком коде я получаю: 1970-01-01` - Потому что `strftime` принимает в себя `strtotime`, а не `date`, видимо

Comment: Точно) Благодарю!!

Comment: @PauloBerezini На самом деле любой может оформить ответ, даже вы можете спокойно, если хотите,  сослаться на комментарии и написать. И даже сам автор вопроса. Но ок, оформил))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, стыдно немножко брать чужой ответ)

Comment: @PauloBerezini [Ответ на вопрос, взятый у другого пользователя из комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/191482) ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я в php не шарю, у меня был опыт неправильного коментария, на языке который я знаю если интересно [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724013/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-java/724237#724237), пожтому я нехочу отвечать неправильно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации, **[strftime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php)** выглядит так:

```
string strftime ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

А это значит, что нужно передавать не `date`, а `strtotime`